# Difference between swagger and loopback for Rest API

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs

[Swagger](http://swagger.io/) helps in creating Restful Api, I get that. Where would you use [LoopBack](http://loopback.io/), is this another tool for creating Rest api. LoopBack has support swagger 2.0. I am confused here, can they be used interchangeably.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo, post it as answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swagger is a documentation framework. If you attach the appropriate annotations to your code, it produces a "live" documentation site that lets users see all your REST services in a visual way, including their request and response formats, with the ability to execute sample calls.

Loopback is a framework that helps you actually write the REST services themselves.

Comment: That is not true at all! http://swagger.io/ swagger have several tools to build REST frameworks.. is not even for documentations! it generates the api docs, that is a feature... as many others @eric

Comment: I agree with @jamesjara. Swagger also generates code scaffolding which gives an initial kick to the development.

Answer (score 7):

Swagger is a powerful open source framework backed by a large ecosystem of tools that helps you design, build, document, and consume your RESTful APIs

You can use the editor , to build the REST specification, without coding, then you use the  Swagger generator to convert this human readable file, into real code on more than 10 languages, you can auto generate server and clients.

Comment: Swagger seems more like an api or library. Where loopback is a framework. Reminds me of React vs Angular. Code more with more control vs code less (or more ridged/set-in-stone style) with less flexibility. Would this be a correct assessment?